# Перевести We are Offline

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Не переведён заголовок страницы (который в заголовке таба написан) о режиме технической поддержки:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Надо на MSE. Нет такой фразы для перевода.